# NiFi 1.22.0, PutSQL Processor does not appear to be executing the input SQL statements

Tags: apache-nifi

The number of PutSQL in one of nifi's processgroups has been increasing, but the number of queued connected to it has not decreased, and the PutSQL does not appear to be executing the input SQL statements.

ProcessGroep config overview:

[ProcessGroep config overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJZGb.jpg)

PutSQL config overview:

[PutSQL config overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUXDo.jpg)

Switching Support Fragmented Transactions from False to True, but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing `PutSQL` with `ExecuteSQL`, resulting in no data backlog in the queue.